# Why isn't my .bashrc file being read from .profile

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc, source

in my `.profile` file I have the line:

```
# source bashrc if it exists
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

to make sure that my `.bashrc` file is sourced if it exists. I also have a set up script that I run on new machines to set up my environment that is for some reason behaving differently.

At the end of the setup script I have:

```
# read .profile
source "$USERDIR/.profile"
```

Where `$USERDIR` points to my home directory.  I know that `.profile` is properly sourced when this script executes because I echo ".profile sourced", and this is printed when the script finishes.

However, the `.bashrc` is not read from `.profile` (when `.profile` is sourced from this setup file).  I can't figure out why because just typing `source .profile` from `bash` works as it should.

I know `.bashrc` is not run because the echo line in my rc file echoes only when I source `.profile` directly and not from this set up script. The `.bashrc` script does exist when I try to source it (so the `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]` should execute) because it is created at the same time .profile is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One step at a time. Add this to `.profile`

```
# source bashrc if it exists
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    echo ".profile is sourcing " ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

and then call bash as login: `bash -l` should be enough.

Does the line: `.profile is sourcing  /home/user/.bashrc` get printed?

If it does, the problem may be with:

- do any of this files exist:  ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login
- is bash being called with the option `--noprofile`?
- or with your setup script.

If it doesn't, the problem is with `.profile` and or `.bashrc`.

- maybe you should use $HOME instead of ~ for the user directory.
- maybe your bashrc has a line to prevent execution when not interactive:

  ```
  # If not running interactively, don't do anything
  [ -z "$PS1" ] && return
  ```

Comment: Ah, your last one is right. `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` is in my `.bashrc`! Foolish.

Answer (score 0):

> Where `$USERDIR` points to my home directory.

And where exactly does `$HOME` point? In bash, `~` always expands to wherever `$HOME` points. If you can't `source ~/.profile` because `$HOME` is not set up correctly, then your `$USERDIR/.profile` won't be able to `source ~/.bashrc`.